# Linux debian command

Tags: linux, wget

i tried to install isp cp omega on my debian dedicated server os, i created a new dir with name `/panel/`, and i wrote a command `cd /panel`, then I run the code

```
wget http://sourceforge.net/projects/ispcp/files/ispCP%20Omega/ispCP%20Omega%201.1.0%20Beta%201/ispcp-omega-1.1.0-beta1.tar.bz2/download#
```

And in folder was created a new file with name `download`, but it should be something like `ispcp-omega.1.1.tar.bz2` and I Can't rar that file, please help me.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have got download.html page.

First - take "direct link" to file from sourceforge.

Second (optional) - point the name of output file.

```
wget http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/ispcp/ispCP%20Omega/ispCP%20Omega%201.1.0%20Beta%201/ispcp-omega-1.1.0-beta1.tar.bz2
```

or

```
wget http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/ispcp/ispCP%20Omega/ispCP%20Omega%201.1.0%20Beta%201/ispcp-omega-1.1.0-beta1.tar.bz2 -O ispcp-omega-1.1.0-beta1.tar.bz2
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
wget -O ispcp-omega.1.1.tar.bz2 http://sourceforge.net/projects/ispcp/files/ispCP%20Omega/ispCP%20Omega%201.1.0%20Beta%201/ispcp-omega-1.1.0-beta1.tar.bz2/download#
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try renaming the file you've downloaded:

```
mv download ispcp-omega.1.1.tar.bz2
```